# Preload 0.6.4 not working

Tags: 12.04, services, preload

I installed preload on a fresh system and I get the following error:

```
[Sun Sep  1 08:59:15 2013] loading conf from /etc/preload.conf
[Sun Sep  1 08:59:15 2013] loading state from /var/lib/preload/preload.state 
[Sun Sep  1 08:59:15 2013] failed reading state from /var/lib/preload/preload.state: line 14491:invalid tag
[Sun Sep  1 08:59:15 2013] Exiting
[Sun Sep  1 12:16:29 2013] loading conf from /etc/preload.conf
[Sun Sep  1 12:16:29 2013] loading state from /var/lib/preload/preload.state
[Sun Sep  1 12:16:29 2013] failed reading state from /var/lib/preload/preload.state: line 14491:invalid tag
[Sun Sep  1 12:16:29 2013] Exiting
```

How can I get preload working? (I need it for better performance.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to remove preload with:

```
sudo apt-get purge preload
```

check if the `/var/lib/preload/preload.state` file is still there. If so remove it:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/preload/preload.state
```

then reinstall

```
sudo apt-get install preload
```

Comment: nO THIS DID Not work for me. see log output below           'code' [Mon Sep  2 21:28:09 2013] loading conf from /etc/preload.conf
     [Mon Sep  2 21:28:09 2013] loading state from /var/lib/preload/preload.state
[Mon Sep  2 21:28:09 2013] cannot open /var/lib/preload/preload.state for reading, ignoring: No such file or directory
[Mon Sep  2 21:34:05 2013] loading conf from /etc/preload.conf
[Mon Sep  2 21:34:05 2013] loading state from /var/lib/preload/preload.state
[Mon Sep  2 21:34:05 2013] cannot open /var/lib/preload/preload.state for reading, ignoring: No such file or directory

Comment: After some trial, it worked, don't know how i did it, may be reboot s, but your idea worked this time.